# Cannot load external module when trying to import i18next in TypeScript

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, typescript, i18next, definitelytyped

One reason why I can't import i18next is because the i18next.d.ts file does not have

```
declare module "i18next" {
    export = i18next;
}
```

at the end, like jquery.d.ts and knockout.d.ts have.
It only has

```
declare var i18next: I18nextStatic;
```

So when I tried to import in my TypeScript file using

```
import i18next = require('i18next');
```

it will barf:
Cannot load external module
Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type

I don't know why Definitely Typed project compose the d.ts file in that way.
And I don't know if declare module will be a good solution or not.

Someone please help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to shim the i18next library.

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: And how to do it in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to Shim the i18next library so that RequireJS defines it as a module.

There's more info on the RequireJS site here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

```
shim : {
   'i18next' : {
      exports : 'i18next'
    }
}
```